# Set pretty printer line width in Z3's C++ API

Tags: z3

I'm trying to change the line width used by Z3's pretty printer, using the C++ API. I've found that there is a flag in `z3/src/ast/pp_params.pyg` that's called `max_width` but I don't know how to set it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a combination of setting the max_width and max_ribbon.

Example:

include "z3++.h"

void main() {
    z3::set_param("pp.max_width", 1000);
    z3::set_param("pp.max_ribbon", 1000);
    z3::context ctx;
    z3::expr x = ctx.bv_const("x", 10);
    z3::expr fml = x & x;
    fml = fml & fml;
    fml = fml & fml;
    fml = fml & fml;
    fml = fml & fml;
    fml = fml & fml;
    fml = fml & fml;
    fml = fml & fml;
    fml = fml & fml;
    fml = fml & fml;
    fml = fml & fml;
    fml = fml & fml;
    std::cout << fml << "\n";
}